# How to Cross strike cell button in swift 4

Tags: swift, strikethrough

How to Cross strike cell button in swift 4

presently i am using the below code to strike button

```
func testString (titleStr : String) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
    let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: titleStr)
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length ))
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 1, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length  ))
    attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range:  NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
    return attributeString
}
```

And get output Like this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D8UH.png): [image]

How to change my code to get output like this
Screen shot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1D8UH.png): [image]

Comment: There's no built-in support in `NSAttributedString` for "cross strike". Perhaps add a view over the label/string where the view draw an "x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `UIBezierPath`. Create `UIView` above the button and set constraints to edges of button - right mouse button click on view and drag to the button:

[image]

hold `shift` and select all edges:

[image]

Then create custom `UIView` class with override `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` method:

```
final class CrossedView: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let path = UIBezierPath()

        path.move(to: .zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width, y: frame.height))

        path .move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: frame.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: frame.width, y: 0))

        UIColor.gray.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
    }

}
```

Next, set `Class` to `CrossedView` in storyboard, run.

[image]

Finally, you get expected result:

[image]

Comment: Without storyboard how can i achive?

Comment: Hi, @GowthamS. Just programmatically create `CrossedView` and add this as subview to the button's superview (view of viewController or cell, or other), setup constraints (4 constraints, one for each edge) and that's it.

Comment: HI ,@pacification Thank you so much its working fine

Comment: @GowthamS, very nice! feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well NSAttributedString has no support for "cross-strike".
You have to add the ImageView with cross strike icon over the UILabel.